# Taking info from one file and printing to another in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to copy the contents of a file that has MANY words and moving the contents into another file. The original file has 3 letter words that i'd like to sort out. unfortunately I have been unsuccessful in getting it to happen. I am newer to Python with some Java experience so im trying to do this pretty basic. Code is as follows:

```
# Files that were going to open
filename = 'words.txt'
file_two = 'new_words.txt'

# Variables were going to use in program

# Program Lists to transfer long words
words = []

# We open the file and store it into our list here
with open(filename, 'r') as file_object:
    for line in file_object:
        words.append(line.rstrip("\n"))

# We transfer the info into the new file
with open(file_two, 'a') as file:
    x = int(0)
    for x in words:
        if len(words[x]) >= 5:
            print(words[x])
            file.write(words[x])
            x += 1
```

I understand my problem is at the bottom while trying to import to the new file and perhaps a simple explanation might get me there, many thanks.

Comment: What exactly happens, and how is it different from your expected behavior? Post the exact error you're getting if any.

Comment: `x` even though you've assigned it as `int`, it's changed to string in the `for` loop.

Comment: The error im getting is:
if len(words[x]) >= 5:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: @VanPeer Interesting, is there a way to make it process as an integer instead?

Comment: @stybl What i want to happen is, if the word is 5 or more characters to be put into the new file "new_words.txt"

Comment: @RobertPerez stybl's answer explains it clearly on how to proceed. you really don't need an `int` there unless it's to compare the length, which is constant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
with open(file_two, 'a') as file:
    x = int(0)
    for x in words:
        if len(words[x]) >= 5:
            print(words[x])
            file.write(words[x])
            x += 1
```

The reason for the error you're getting is that `x` isn't a number once the loop begins. It is a string.

I think you misunderstand how for loops work in python. They're more akin to foreach loops from other languages. When you do `for x in words`, `x` is given the value of the first element in `words`, then the second, and so on for each iteration. You however are trying to treat it like a normal for loop, going through the list by index. Of course this doesn't work.

There are two ways to go about fixing your code. You can either take the foreach approach:

```
with open(file_two, 'w') as file:
    for x in words: #x is a word
        if len(x) >= 5:
            print(x)
            file.write(x)
```

Or, use `len()` to loop through the *range* of indices of the list. This will yield behavior similar to that of a traditional for loop:

```
with open(file_two, 'a') as file:
    for x in range(len(words)): #x is a number
        if len(words[x]) >= 5:
            print(words[x])
            file.write(words[x])
```

There is also no need to manually increment `x`, or to give `x` an initial value, as it is reassigned at the beginning of the for loop.

Comment: MANY MANY thanks! I tried a few different things on my end before posting on here. I took the first method you supplied and it worked. Also thank you for the explanation of the loop, since i'm used to Java, the fact that x was holding the information and not an integer was throwing me off.